# Derivatives Impicit

Tags: implicit-differentiation

(1) Use implicit differentiation to find the derivative of : 
(1) xy^3/1+y = e^xy 
I got my final answer as dy/dx = [y^6 +xy^3 - ye^xy ( y+1)^2] / [ ( xe^xy) (y+1)^2 - 3xy^5] Anyone got another answer with correct steps?

Comment: Do you mean:
$$\frac{xy^3}{1+y}=e^{xy}$$
And:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^6+xy^3-ye^{xy}(y+1)^2}{xe^{xy}(y+1)^2-3xy^5}$$

Comment: I rolled back the edit, since it is unclear what the OP meant by the two equations *"xy^3/1+y = e^xy"* and *"dy/dx = [y^6 +xy^3 - ye^xy ( y+1)^2] / [ ( xe^xy) (y+1)^2 - 3xy^5]"*.

Answer (score 1):

Our starting point is
$$ \frac{xy^3}{1 + y} = e^{xy}$$
Differentiating both sides w.r.t. $x$,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \left( \frac{xy^3}{1 + y} \right) = \frac{d}{dx} \left( e^{xy} \right)$$
$$ \Rightarrow \frac{y^3}{1 + y} + x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{d}{dy} \frac{y^3}{1 + y} = \frac{d(xy)}{dx} \cdot \frac{d}{d(xy)} e^{xy}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{y^3}{1 + y} + x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{3y^2(1 + y) - y^3}{(1 + y)^2} = \left(y + x \frac{dy}{dx} \right) \cdot e^{xy}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{y^3}{1 + y} + x \cdot \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{2y^3 + 3y^2}{(1 + y)^2} = \left(y + x \frac{dy}{dx} \right) \cdot e^{xy}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} \left( x \cdot \frac{2y^3 + 3y^2}{(1 + y)^2} - x \cdot e^{xy} \right) = y \cdot e^{xy} - \frac{y^3}{1 + y}$$
Now from here there are many variations of the final answer depending on how you want to use the substitution $ \frac{xy^3}{1 + y} = e^{xy}$. For example, we can write
$$\frac{2xy^3}{(1 + y)^2} = \frac{xy^3}{1 + y} \cdot \frac{2}{1 + y} = \frac{2e^{xy}}{1 + y} $$
So it's a bit hard to verify the answer that you arrived at. Perhaps you could compare with the above and let us know if you're more confident in your answer now.

Comment: Thanks. I realised where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

When I face this kind of problem, I personally prefer to use the implicit function. In your case $$F=\frac{xy^3}{1 + y} - e^{xy}=0$$ Now, compute each derivative $$F'_x=\frac{y^3}{1 + y} - ye^{xy}$$ $$F'_y=\frac{x y^2 (2 y+3)}{(y+1)^2}-x e^{x y}$$ Now, using the implicit function theorem
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{F'_x}{F'_y}=\frac{y (y+1) \left((y+1) e^{x y}-y^2\right)}{x y^2 (2 y+3)-x (y+1)^2 e^{x y}}$$